# Stream RTMP to RTSP using vlc

Tags: amazon-ec2, vlc, rtsp, rtmp

i just want to stream my RTMP live Streaming to RTSP using VLC Software. 
i was tested these streaming conversation in my local, the rtmp to rtsp streaming conversation working perfectly in my local side. the following code is working for local conversation

```
vlc -vvv rtmp://xxxxxx.com/jiljillive/live2 --sout '#rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=8554,sdp=rtsp://localhost:8554/test.sdp}'
```

After this i was done same thing in my AWS EC2 instance .
i am doing these protocol conversation in EC2 ubuntu 12.04 64bit. this is my command

```
vlc -vvv rtmp://xxxxx.com/live/live2 --sout '#rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=8554,sdp=rtsp://xxxxxx:8554/test.sdp}'
```

this time streaming rtsp. but when i call the rtsp url to vlc for play , its not working

the following is AWSEC2 rtmp to rtsp console return code

```
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 2.0.8 Twoflower
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2013 VLC authors and VideoLAN
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: configured with ./configure  '--enable-static' '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' '--config-cache' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-silent-rules' '--disable-update-check' '--enable-fast-install' '--prefix=/usr' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/vlc-nox' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--with-binary-version=0ubuntu0.12.04.1' '--enable-a52' '--enable-aa' '--enable-bluray' '--enable-bonjour' '--enable-caca' '--enable-dbus' '--enable-dca' '--enable-dirac' '--enable-directfb' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--enable-dvdnav' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-fluidsynth' '--enable-freetype' '--enable-fribidi' '--enable-gnutls' '--enable-jack' '--enable-kate' '--enable-libass' '--enable-libmpeg2' '--enable-libproxy' '--enable-libxml2' '--enable-lirc' '--enable-live555' '--enable-mad' '--enable-mkv' '--enable-mod' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-mtp' '--enable-mux_ogg' '--enable-ncurses' '--enable-notify' '--enable-ogg' '--enable-oss' '--enable-pulse' '--enable-qt4' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-samplerate' '--enable-schroedinger' '--enable-sdl' '--enable-shout' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-smb' '--enable-speex' '--enable-svg' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-upnp' '--enable-vcd' '--enable-vcdx' '--enable-vorbis' '--enable-x264' '--enable-zvbi' '--with-kde-solid=/usr/share/kde4/apps/solid/actions/' '--disable-dxva2' '--disable-gnomevfs' '--disable-goom' '--disable-portaudio' '--disable-projectm' '--disable-sqlite' '--disable-telx' '--enable-alsa' '--enable-atmo' '--enable-dc1394' '--enable-dv' '--enable-fbosd' '--enable-libva' '--enable-linsys' '--enable-omxil' '--enable-pvr' '--enable-udev' '--enable-v4l2' '--enable-crystalhd' '--enable-mmx' '--enable-sse' '--disable-neon' '--disable-altivec' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu'
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/lib/vlc/plugins'
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: saving plugins cache /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 420 modules
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: opening config file (/home/ubuntu/.config/vlc/vlcrc)
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "C"
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 FPU 
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: looking for memcpy module: 4 candidates
[0x10ae108] main libvlc debug: using memcpy module "memcpymmxext"
[0x12d8028] main input debug: Creating an input for 'Media Library'
[0x12d8028] main input debug: Input is a meta file: disabling unneeded options
[0x12d8028] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
[0x12d8028] main input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' gives access `file' demux `xspf-open' path `/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x12d8028] main input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x10debc8] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module: 3 candidates
[0x10debc8] main demux debug: no access_demux module matching "file" could be loaded
[0x10debc8] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.740 ms - Total 1.740 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.740 ms)
[0x12d8028] main input debug: creating access 'file' location='/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf', path='/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x11798b8] main access debug: looking for access module: 2 candidates
[0x11798b8] filesystem access debug: opening file `/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x11798b8] main access debug: using access module "filesystem"
[0x11798b8] main access debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.005 ms - Total 1.005 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.005 ms)
[0x1179a08] main stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[0x1179a08] main stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[0x1179a08] main stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[0x1179a08] main stream debug: pre-buffering done 296 bytes in 0s - 1338 KiB/s
[0x1179c68] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 7 candidates
[0x1179c68] main stream debug: no stream_filter module matching "any" could be loaded
[0x1179c68] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.856 ms - Total 1.856 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.856 ms)
[0x1179c68] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 1 candidate
[0x1179c68] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "stream_filter_record"
[0x1179c68] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.591 ms - Total 0.591 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.591 ms)
[0x12d8028] main input debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='xspf-open' location='/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[0x117d4a8] main demux debug: looking for demux module: 1 candidate
[0x117d4a8] playlist demux debug: using XSPF playlist reader
[0x117d4a8] main demux debug: using demux module "playlist"
[0x117d4a8] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.859 ms - Total 0.859 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.859 ms)
[0x117ddf8] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module: 2 candidates
[0x117ddf8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x117ddf8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x117ddf8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[0x117ddf8] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x117ddf8] main demux meta debug: no meta reader module matching "any" could be loaded
[0x117ddf8] main demux meta debug: TIMER module_need() : 3.735 ms - Total 3.735 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 3.735 ms)
[0x12d8028] main input debug: `file/xspf-open:///home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' successfully opened
[0x10dff08] main xml reader debug: looking for xml reader module: 1 candidate
[0x10dff08] main xml reader debug: using xml reader module "xml"
[0x10dff08] main xml reader debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.285 ms - Total 1.285 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.285 ms)
[0x117d4a8] playlist demux debug: parsed 0 tracks successfully
[0x12d8028] main input debug: EOF reached
[0x117d4a8] main demux debug: removing module "playlist"
[0x1179c68] main stream debug: removing module "stream_filter_record"
[0x11798b8] main access debug: removing module "filesystem"
[0x12d8028] main input debug: TIMER input launching for 'Media Library' : 13.537 ms - Total 13.537 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 13.537 ms)
[0x10de898] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
[0x10de898] main interface debug: using interface module "hotkeys"
[0x10de898] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.554 ms - Total 0.554 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.554 ms)
[0x12d8028] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
[0x12d8028] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[0x12d8028] main interface debug: no interface module matching "inhibit,none" could be loaded
[0x12d8028] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.766 ms - Total 0.766 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.766 ms)
[0x12d8028] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x10c1b58] main playlist debug: playlist threads correctly activated
[0x10c1b58] main playlist debug: adding item `rtmp://xxxxxx.com/live/live2' ( rtmp://emedias.com/jiljillive/live2 )
[0x10c1b58] main playlist debug: no fetch required for (null) (art currently (null))
[0x10c1b58] main playlist debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
[0x10c1b58] main playlist debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index -1
[0x12d8028] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 1 candidate
[0x12d8028] main interface debug: no interface module matching "globalhotkeys,none" could be loaded
[0x12d8028] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 25.490 ms - Total 25.490 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 25.490 ms)
[0x12d8028] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x10ae108] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x10ae108] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x12d8028] main interface debug: looking for interface module: 6 candidates
[0x12d8028] qt4 interface error: Could not connect to X server
[0x12d8028] skins2 interface debug: Cannot open X display
[0x12d8028] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory
[0x12d8028] [cli] lua interface debug: Found lua interface script: /usr/lib/vlc/lua/intf/cli.luac
[0x12d8028] [cli] main interface debug: using interface module "lua"
[0x12d8028] [cli] main interface debug: TIMER module_need() : 3.196 ms - Total 3.196 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 3.196 ms)
[0x10c1b58] main playlist debug: processing request item: null, node: Playlist, skip: 0
[0x10c1b58] main playlist debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
[0x10c1b58] main playlist debug: resyncing on rtmp://xxxxxx.com/jiljillive/live2
[0x10c1b58] main playlist debug: rtmp://xxxxxxxx.com/jiljillive/live2 is at 0
[0x10c1b58] main playlist debug: creating new input thread
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Creating an input for 'rtmp://xxxxxxx.com/live/live2'
[0x7f7230000e98] main stream output debug: using sout chain=`rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=8554,sdp=rtsp://xxxxxx:8554/test.sdp}'
[0x7f7230000e98] main stream output debug: stream=`rtp'
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out debug: looking for sout stream module: 1 candidate
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-rtp-dst to 127.0.0.1
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-rtp-port to 8554
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out debug: set config option: sout-rtp-sdp to rtsp://54.254.180.206:8554/test.sdp
[0x7f7230001298] stream_out_rtp stream out warning: "54.254.180.206" RTSP host might be ignored in multiple-host configurations, use at your own risks.
[0x7f7230001298] stream_out_rtp stream out: Consider passing --rtsp-host=IP on the command line instead.
[0x7f7230001298] stream_out_rtp stream out debug: RTSP stream at /test.sdp
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out debug: net: listening to 54.254.180.206 port 8554
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out error: socket bind error (Permission denied)
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out error: cannot create socket(s) for HTTP host
[0x12d8028] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
> [0x7f7230001298] stream_out_rtp stream out error: cannot export SDP as RTSP
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out debug: using sout stream module "stream_out_rtp"
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out debug: TIMER module_need() : 4.739 ms - Total 4.739 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 4.739 ms)
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: `rtmp://xxxxxx.com/live/live2' gives access `rtmp' demux `' path `xxxxxxx.com/live/live2'
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: creating demux: access='rtmp' demux='' location='emedias.com/jiljillive/live2' file='(null)'
[0x7f7230005ea8] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module: 0 candidates
[0x7f7230005ea8] main demux debug: no access_demux module matched "rtmp"
[0x7f7230005ea8] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.330 ms - Total 0.330 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.330 ms)
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: creating access 'rtmp' location='xxxxxx.com/jiljillive/live2', path='(null)'
[0x7f7230004828] main access debug: looking for access module: 1 candidate
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
[0x7f7230004828] access_avio access debug: not seekable, size=-38
[0x7f7230004828] main access debug: using access module "access_avio"
[0x7f7230004828] main access debug: TIMER module_need() : 201.525 ms - Total 201.525 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 201.525 ms)
[0x7f72300060c8] main stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[0x7f72300060c8] main stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[0x7f72300060c8] main stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[0x7f72300060c8] main stream debug: pre-buffering done 569 bytes in 0s - 8053 KiB/s
[0x7f723050fcd8] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 7 candidates
[0x7f723050fcd8] main stream debug: no stream_filter module matching "any" could be loaded
[0x7f723050fcd8] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.514 ms - Total 1.514 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.514 ms)
[0x7f723050fcd8] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module: 1 candidate
[0x7f723050fcd8] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "stream_filter_record"
[0x7f723050fcd8] main stream debug: TIMER module_need() : 0.432 ms - Total 0.432 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 0.432 ms)
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: creating demux: access='rtmp' demux='' location='xxxxx.com/jiljillive/live2' file='(null)'
[0x7f723050fa48] main demux debug: looking for demux module: 54 candidates
[0x7f723050fa48] mod demux debug: MOD validation failed (ext=)
[0x7f723050fa48] ts demux debug: TS module discarded (lost sync)
[0x7f723050fa48] avformat demux debug: trying url: rtmp://xxxxxx.com/jiljillive/live2
[0x7f723050fa48] avformat demux debug: detected format: flv
[flv @ 0x7f723112e520] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: selecting program id=0
[0x7f723050fa48] avformat demux debug: adding es: video codec = h264
[0x7f723050fa48] avformat demux debug: adding es: audio codec = mpga
[0x7f723050fa48] avformat demux debug: AVFormat supported stream
[0x7f723050fa48] avformat demux debug:     - format = flv (FLV format)
[0x7f723050fa48] avformat demux debug:     - start time = 0
[0x7f723050fa48] avformat demux debug:     - duration = -1
[0x7f723050fa48] main demux debug: using demux module "avformat"
[0x7f723050fa48] main demux debug: TIMER module_need() : 3321.579 ms - Total 3321.579 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 3321.579 ms)
[0x7f723112f8d8] main decoder debug: looking for packetizer module: 21 candidates
[0x7f723112f8d8] packetizer_h264 decoder debug: found NAL_SPS (sps_id=0)
[0x7f723112f8d8] packetizer_h264 decoder debug: found NAL_PPS (pps_id=0 sps_id=0)
[0x7f723112f8d8] packetizer_h264 decoder debug: avcC length size=4, sps=1, pps=1
[0x7f723112f8d8] main decoder debug: using packetizer module "packetizer_h264"
[0x7f723112f8d8] main decoder debug: TIMER module_need() : 5.143 ms - Total 5.143 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 5.143 ms)
[0x7f7231110088] main decoder debug: looking for packetizer module: 21 candidates
[0x7f7231110088] main decoder debug: using packetizer module "mpeg_audio"
[0x7f7231110088] main decoder debug: TIMER module_need() : 2.111 ms - Total 2.111 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 2.111 ms)
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: starting in async mode
[0x7f72311f2248] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module: 2 candidates
[0x7f72311f2248] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /home/ubuntu/.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x7f72311f2248] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x7f72311f2248] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[0x7f72311f2248] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[0x7f72311f2248] main demux meta debug: no meta reader module matching "any" could be loaded
[0x7f72311f2248] main demux meta debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.727 ms - Total 1.727 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.727 ms)
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: `rtmp://xxxxxx.com/live/live2' successfully opened
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: switching to sync mode
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[0x7f7231110088] mpeg_audio decoder debug: MPGA channels:1 samplerate:22050 bitrate:48
[0x7f7230000e98] main stream output debug: adding a new sout input (sout_input:0x7f7218000a00)
[0x7f7230001298] stream_out_rtp stream out debug: maximum RTP packet size: 1400 bytes
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out debug: net: connecting to [127.0.0.1]:8554
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out debug: net: connecting to [127.0.0.1]:8555 from [127.0.0.1]:42582
[0x7f7230001298] stream_out_rtp stream out debug: sdp=
v=0
o=- 15466995737973131073 15466995737973131073 IN IP4 ip-172-31-10-174
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
a=tool:vlc 2.0.8
a=recvonly
a=type:broadcast
a=charset:UTF-8
m=audio 8554 RTP/AVP 14
b=AS:48
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:14 MPA/90000

[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Stream buffering done (697 ms in 6 ms)
[0x7f7238000bd8] main input debug: Decoder buffering done in 0 ms
[0x7f7230000e98] main stream output debug: adding a new sout input (sout_input:0x7f7220009d60)
[0x7f7230001298] stream_out_rtp stream out debug: maximum RTP packet size: 1400 bytes
[0x7f7230001298] stream_out_rtp stream out debug: we found a startcode for NAL with TYPE:7
[0x7f7230001298] stream_out_rtp stream out debug: we found a startcode for NAL with TYPE:8
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out debug: net: connecting to [127.0.0.1]:8556
[0x7f7230001298] main stream out debug: net: connecting to [127.0.0.1]:8557 from [127.0.0.1]:35164
[0x7f7230001298] stream_out_rtp stream out debug: sdp=
v=0
o=- 15466995737982916361 15466995737982916361 IN IP4 ip-172-31-10-174
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
a=tool:vlc 2.0.8
a=recvonly
a=type:broadcast
a=charset:UTF-8
m=audio 8554 RTP/AVP 14
b=AS:48
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:14 MPA/90000
m=video 8556 RTP/AVP 96
b=RR:0
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42801f;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0KAH5ZUCg/YCoQAAA+gAAHUw4GAAnrAABGMP8Y4O0JE1A==,aM41IA==;
```

Comment: Isn't this better suited for superuser.com or am I missing the programming aspect of this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that VLC can currently stream directly to RTMP. A couple sources that seem to confirm this: [videolanForumLink](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=97324), [wowzaForumLink](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?16655-RTP-%28VLC%29-to-RTMP-%28Wowza%29-to-flashPlayer%28Website%29).

However, it sounds like VLC may be able to be used in conjunction with other software - I've never tried this.

Alternatively, consider these common software tools (I've used these) used to stream to RTMP, though these may not directly do what you are trying to accomplish (these are good for streaming a webcam feed, or capturing a live video game for example).

- Open Broadcaster Software
- XSplit Broadcaster
- Flash Media Encoder